# any singular + any plural + verb?

Tags: pronouns, plural-forms, singular

I have the following sentence:

> It shows up when any organization or preset settings are saved.

It uses any with a singular noun (organization) then comes a plural noun (settings), should be followed by 'are saved'? Or should I rephrase to:

> It shows up when any organization or preset setting is saved.

Comment: The verb follows the closest noun. In *theory*, because *settings* is plural, it should *are*. But in reality the sentence should be rephrased so as to avoid the awkwardness.

Comment: Also note that in the first you are talking about a (plural) collection of *settings* and in the second about a (singular) *setting*.

Comment: So if I would need to use settings in plural, how could I rephrase it?